# Provide example of key for dictionary in swagger

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have a response which is a JSON object with keys. I would like to set an example for the key but if I provide an example it gets treated as an example of the whole object and overrides the nested properties.

Way 1:

In the image below, zone should be the name of the key and then I'd like to provide a separate string as an example of what that zone could be.

[image]

This is how I have it defined currently:

[image]

Way 2:

If I try to use additionalProperties like:

[image]

Then the example and model look like this where I'm also not able to provide a name and example for the key:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get it most of the way by using way 1 and providing a full example at the root level:
[image]

Which results in

[image]

and

[image]